# Verifying my understanding of the scope chain

Tags: javascript, scope-chain

**(Question 1)** 
In Flanagan's JS Definitive Guide, he defines the `Function` method `bind()` in case it's not available (wasn't available n ECMAScript 3).

It looks like this:

```
function bind(f, o) {
    if (f.bind) return f.bind(o);     // Use the bind method, if there is one
    else return function() {          // Otherwise, bind it like this
        return f.apply(o, arguments);
    };
}
```

He illustrates the use of it with an example (which I have modified to change the 3rd line from `f.bind(o)`):

```
function f(y) { return this.x + y; } // This function needs to be bound
var o = { x : 1 };                   // An object we'll bind to
var g = bind(f, o);                  // Calling g(x) invokes o.f(x)
g(2)                                 // => 3
```

When I first saw this, I thought "Wouldn't `arguments` refer to the arguments variable within the bind function we're defining? But we want the arguments property of the function we eventually apply it to, like g in the example above..."

I verified that his example did indeed work and surmised that the line `return f.apply(o, arguments)` isn't evaluated until `var g = bind(f, o)` up above. That is, I thought, when you return a function, are you just returning the source code for that function, no? Until its evaluated? So I tested this theory by trying out a slightly different version of bind:

```
function mybind2(f, o) {
    var arguments = 6;
    return function() {          // Otherwise, bind it like this
        return f.apply(o, arguments);
    };
}
```

If it's simply returning tbe unevaluated function source, there's no way that it stores `arguments = 6` when later evaluated, right? And after checking, I still got `g(2)` => 3. But then I realized -- if it's just returning unevaluated code, how is the `o` in `return f.apply(o, arguments)` getting passed?

So I decided that what must be happening is this:

The `o` and the `arguments` variables (even when `arguments` equals 6) *are* getting passed on to the function. It's just that when the function `g` is eventually called, the `arguments` variable is redefined by the interpreter to be the arguments of `g` (in `g(2)`) and hence the original value of arguments that I tried to pass on was replaced. But this implies that it was sort of storing the function as text up until then, because otherwise `o` and `arguments` would have simply been data in the program, rather than variables that could be overwritten. Is this explanation correct?

**(Question 2)** Earlier on the same page, he defines the following function which makes use the `apply` method to trace a function for debugging:

```
function trace(o, m) {
    var original = o[m];  // Remember original method in the closure.
    o[m] = function() {   // Now define the new method.
        console.log(new Date(), "Entering:", m);      // Log message.
        var result = original.apply(this, arguments); // Invoke original.
        console.log(new Date(), "Exiting:", m);       // Log message.
        return result;                                // Return result.
    };
}
```

Wouldn't the `this` here refer to the function that we're defining, rather than the object `o`? Or are those two things one and the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question 1

For your first question, let's simplify the example so it's clear what being done:

```
function bind(func, thisArg) {
    return function () {
        return func.apply(thisArg, arguments);
    };
}
```

What happens here is that a closure is created that allows the access of the original function and the value of `this` that is passed. The anonymous function returned will keep the original function in its scope, which ends up being like the following:

```
var func = function () {};
var thisArg = {};
func.apply(thisArg, [/*arguments*/]);
```

About your issue with `arguments`, that variable is *implicitly* defined in the scope of all functions created, so therefore **the inner `arguments` will shadow the outer `arguments`**, making it work as expected.

### Question 2

Your problem is to your misunderstanding of the late binding of `this` -- this is one of the more confusing things about JavaScript to people used to more object-oriented languages that also have their own `this` keyword. The value of `this` is only set when it is called, and where it is called defines the value of `this` when it is called. It is simply **the value of the parent object from where it is at the time the function is called**, with the exception of cases where the `this` value is overridden.

For example, see this:

```
function a() {return this;};
a(); // global object;
var b = {};
b.a = a;
b.a(); // object b
```

If `this` was set when the function was defined, calling `b.a` would result in the global object, not the `b` object. Let's also simplify what happens with the second function given:

```
function trace(obj, property) {
    var method = obj[property];  // Remember original method in the closure.
    obj[property] = function () {   // Now define the new method.
        console.log(1); // Log message.
        // Invoke original method and return its result
        return original.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

What happens in this case is that the original method is stored in a closure. Assigning to the object that the method was originally in does not overwrite the `method` object. Just like a normal method assignment, the principles of the `this` value still work the same -- it will return the parent object, not the function that you've defined. If you do a simple assignment:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = function () { return this; };
obj.foo(); // obj
```

It does what was expected, returns the parent object at the time of calling. Placing your code in a nested function makes no difference in this regard.

#### Some good resources

If you'd like to learn more about writing code in JavaScript, I'd highly recommend taking a look at [Fully Understanding the `this` Keyword](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/fully-understanding-the-this-keyword) by Cody Lindley -- it goes into much more detail about how the `this` keyword behaves in different contexts and the things you can do with it.

Comment: Thanks - that cleared it up a lot. I think I understand how `this` works now.

Answer (score 2):

> But this implies that it was sort of storing the function as text up until then, because otherwise o and arguments would have simply been data in the program, rather than variables that could be overwritten. Is this explanation correct?

No. `this` and `arguments` are just special variables which are *implicitly* set when a function is *executed*. They don't adhere to normal "closure rules". The function definition itself is still evaluated immediately and `bind` returns a function object.
You can easily verify this with:

```
var g = bind(f, o);
console.log(typeof g);
```

Here is a simpler example which doesn't involve higher order functions:

```
var arguments = 42;
function foo() {
    console.log(arguments);
}
foo(1, 2);
```

I think you see that the definition of `foo` is evaluated like you'd expect. Yet, `console.log(arguments)` logs `[1, 2]` and not `42`.

> Wouldn't the `this` here refer to the function that we're defining, rather than the object o? Or are those two things one and the same?

`this` **never** refers to the function itself (unless you *explicitly* set it so). The value of `this` is completely determined by *how* the function is called. That's why `this` is often called "the context". [The MDN documentation provides extensive information about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

---

Reading material:

- [MDN - `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [MDN - `arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)